# How Docker can be used for multi-layered application?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand how docker can be used to dockerize multilayered application.

My tomcat application needs mongodb, mysql, redis, solr and rabbitmq. I am playing with Docker for couple of weeks now. I am able to install and use mongo/mysql containers. But I am not getting how can I completely ship application using Docker. I have few questions.

How should the images be. Should I have one image that has all the components installed or have separate images (like one for tomcat,  one for mongo, one for mysql etc) and start those containers using a bash script outside of docker.

What is the docker way of maintaining multiple containers at once. Meaning say I have multiple containers (like mongo, mysql, tomcat etc...) that needs to be worked together to run my application, Is there any inbuilt way of dealing this so that one command/script does this?

Suppose I dockerize my application, how can i manage various routine tasks that need to be performed like incremental code deployment, database patches etc. Currently we are using vagrant, we also use fabric along with vagrant for various tasks.Like after vagrant up we use fab tasks for all kind of routine things like code deployment, db refresh, adding volumes, start/stop services etc. What would be the docker's way of doing this?

With Vagrant if VM crashes due to High CPU etc. host system is not affected. But I see docker is eating up lot of host resources. Can we put limits for that say not more than one cpu core for that container etc..?

Because we use vagrant, most of the questions above are in that context. When started with docker I thought docker as a kind of visualization technology that can be a replacement for our huge Vagrant based infra. Please correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to look at [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/):

- you'll be able to define an architecture of your application
- you can then easily build it and run it (with one command)
- pretty much same setup for dev and prod

Answer (score 1):

For microservices, composition etc I won't repost on this.

For containet resource allocation:

Docker run has various resource control options (using google cgroups) see my gist here

https://gist.github.com/afolarin/15d12a476e40c173bf5f